# How to query orchestrate.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was searching for an easy and simple database for a little highscore system for a some games I'm developing in javascript.
I saw [Orchestrate.io](https://orchestrate.io/) in github's student developer pack. I found a suitable drivermodule [nodejs orchestrate](https://www.npmjs.org/package/orchestrate) and have integrated them.

The problem comes with querying orchestrate for my data. I have managed saving scores and querying them with `db.list('collection')`, but this seems to not responding with all data. It appered to me that some values are not returned.

I read about the `db.search('collection','query')` function. But I don't really understand how I could return all data because I don't want to query in a specific way.
My objects are as simple as follows:

```
{"name":"Jack","score":1337}
```

As I understand, one has to send a key, when putting such values to an orchestrate-collection. But I'd like to query the whole collection and get the values in a descendant order in regard to the score.

As for now I end up sorting the result on the client-side.
I hope you guys can give me some hints for a query that can sort for specific values!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the option to use a SearchBuilder

`db.newSearchBuilder()           //Build a search object
       .collection('collection') //Set the collection to be searched
       .sort(score, 'desc')      //Set the order of the results
       .query("*")                //Empty search
       .then(function (res) {    //Callback function for results
                                 //Do something with the results
        })`

[Source](https://orchestrate.io/docs/apiref#search)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But using this approach I got an error telling me the query is required. Seems that it won't accect an empty string. Is there any other way to perform an _all_ query with orchestrate?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards the right direction. The way to query all elements is to set `.query("*")`. If you'd like to update your proposed solution, I will accept your answer!

Comment: Answer updated. Thanks for letting me know of the error, I will be using this myself in the near future.

Comment: It won't return more than 10 by default

Answer (score 0):

By default, .list uses a pagination limit of 10. You can either increase that, e.g.:

```
db.list('collection', { limit: 100 })
```

Or use .links, .links.next (from the docs):

```
db.list('collection', { limit: 10 })
.then(function (page1) {
  // Got First Page
  if (page1.links && page1.links.next) {
    page1.links.next.get().then(function (page2) {
      // Got Second Page
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Keep in mind folks that you can't set a large limit , it won't go more than 100